# Fields are getting overlap on window size decrease vf page

Tags: visualforce, bootstrap

I have this below vf page. When i try to decrease the browser screen the fields are getting overlap. How to avoid this. I am using bootstrap in vf page -

Below is the screenshot -

[image]

```
  <div style="background-color: #7dbed2;" class="panel panel-primary form-inline">
        <br/>
        <apex:form id="theForm" style="background: #f4f7f8;border-radius: 8px; width:75%; padding: 20px; margin:auto;">
        <apex:pageMessages id="msgs" escape="false" rendered="true"/>
            <div class="panel panel-primary" style="background-color:#f4f7f8;">
                <div class="panel-heading" style="font-size: 14px;">Test</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row" id="searchBar">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" style="">
                            <div class="field_label " id="adflabel">Test</div>
                            <div class="form-group" style="width:154px">
                                <apex:actionRegion >
                                    <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!site.Site__c}" styleClass="chzn-select" >
                                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!Products}"></apex:selectOptions>
                                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="popProduct" action="{!fetchProduct}">
                                        <apex:param name="Site__c" value="{!site.Site__c}" assignTo="{!selectedSite}" />
                                        </apex:actionSupport>
                                    </apex:selectList>
                                </apex:actionRegion>   
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-2">
                            <apex:outputPanel id="popProduct"> <script language="javascript">renderChosen(); </script>
                            <div class="field_label " id="productlabel">Account</div>
                            <div class="form-group" style="width:154px">
                                <apex:actionRegion >
                                    <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!site.Product__c}"  styleClass="chzn-select" style=""  id="productId" label="select your options" >
                                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!calProdList}"></apex:selectOptions>
                                    </apex:selectList> 
                                </apex:actionRegion>
                            </div>
                            </apex:outputPanel>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" style="">
                            <div class="field_label " id="adflabel">Opportunity</div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <apex:inputField value="{!parent.Advertiser__c}" styleClass="child_fields"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                       <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" style="">
                            <div class="field_label " id="adflabel">Status</div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <apex:inputField value="{!parent.Status__c}" styleClass="child_fields"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-1" style="border-right: 2px solid #337ab7;height: 53px;">&nbsp;   
                     </div> 
                       <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3" style="">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <div id='caljump' style="position: relative;top: 10px;" class="">
                                 <select id='months' class="form-control" style="border:1px solid #ccc;"></select>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </apex:form>
        <br/>
    </div>
```

Comment: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B56AMEAZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try to replace your classes: "col-md-2" by "col-lg-2".

col-md-* is used for windows bigger than 992px and col-lg-* for windows bigger than 1200px.

So currently, if you decrease the size of your window and its size stay superior to 992px, boostrap sill applies your columns.

Whereas if you use "col-lg-2", Bootstrap will apply your other classes: "col-xs-10" when the window size is inferior to 1200px.

You can create your own column class by adding this in your css:

```
@media (min-width: 1360px){
    .col-custom-lg-2 {
        float: left;
        width: 16.66666667%;
        position: relative;
        min-height: 1px;
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Martin.. When the fields are just touching each other the screen is that time 1360.. in 1200 its still overlapping. Can we override this with 1360.

Comment: Yes. I edited my answer. Just replace your "col-md-2" columns by "col-custom-lg-2" and add the css in your page.